# Why does modern GCC compile files as PIE by default?

Tags: gcc, position-independent-code

As far as I know PIC is used primarily for shared libs, so there is no intent for GCC to compile an executable as PIE unless it was hinted to do it. Also PIE executables are not so useful because in every process' virtual address space there will be only one executable image that started it, and PIEs were made to be loaded several times at different virtual bases.

Comment: "PIE by default" is a patch that some distributions apply, I don't think it is the default in the official gcc.

Comment: @MarcGlisse It's used as default in all major distros so most users consider it GCC's default (not that's its good or correct, just a sad reality).

Answer (score 0):

PIE allows dynamic loader to *randomize* process location in virtual address space (via so called [ASLR](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=overview-address-space-layout-randomization) technology) which helps against certain types of attacks.

Note that program segments are mapped as read-only which allows kernel to reuse same set of physical pages and not waste memory (except for the `.got` relocation segment).

Comment: It sounds a lot like you think that in order for ASLR to work on an OS, OS has to use PIEs instead of non-PIEs all the time. Is it right? If so, PIEs all run as userspace programs, then why does Linux have randomize_va_space sysfs config that obviously alter kernel behaviour?

Comment: non-PIE is an executable compiled as position dependent, GCC allows it with -no-pie flag

Comment: "think that in order for ASLR to work on an OS, OS has to use PIEs instead of non-PIEs all the time" - not quite, even if executable is compiled _without PIE_ kernel will still be able to randomize at least shared libraries.

Comment: "If so, PIEs all run as userspace programs, then why does Linux have randomize_va_space sysfs config that obviously alter kernel behaviour?" - I'm not sure I understood the question but memory mapping of executables is done by the kernel and this parameter controls how hard kernel tries to randomize the positions of loaded segments.